# jQuery mobile form validation not working if I get in the form page using a link with data-ajax=true

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am learning jQuery Mobile building the simplest single page template application: main page and a little form.
In this form I have a single text field that I want to be required.

Here's my link to the form page:

```
<a href="form.html">Form</a>
```

In the form page I have all the key elements: the jquery validation plugin (and jquery before it, of course), the validation script, the mandatory field and the submit button:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#field").validate();
});
</script>
<input type="text" id="field" name="field" class="required" required>
<input id="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Inserisci" data-theme="a"/>
```

If I get in the form page using the normal link the validation won't happen (simple page reload because my form action is not yet set).
If I change my form link to:

```
<a href="form.html" data-ajax=false>Form</a>
```

The validation works and tells me to insert my data in the mandatory field.
But, even if insert data, it'll keep on asking me to insert it without submitting the form.

I really can't understand what I'm doing wrong...

After the 1st suggestion I've kept on reading and I've updated my code with this example: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/jquerymobile.html and the problem is now that I am forced to refresh the form page to see the validation working. If I use data-ajax=false on the link that leads me to the form then validation is always perfectly working.

**Update:**
to be sure that everything is "as vanilla" as possible I got the main template from jquery documentation as starting page, my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>My Page</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
        <body>
                <div data-role="page" id="cruscotto">
                        <div data-role="header" id="header">
                                <h1>page</h1>
                        </div><!-- /header -->
                        <div data-role="content">
                                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="a">
                                        <li>
                                                <a href="inserisci_clienti.html">Inserimento clienti</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                                <a href="ricerca_clienti.html">Ricerca clienti</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                                <a href="about.html">Gestione pagamenti</a>
                                        </li>
                                </ul>
                        </div><!-- /content -->
                          <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a">
            <div class="ui-bar">
             <a href="" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-u" data-theme="a" style="float:right;" class="returnTopAction">Torna su</a>
           </div>
          </div>
                </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

And then I got a perfectly working form from a tutorial, my inserisci_clienti.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>



  <style type='text/css'>
    label.error {
    color: red;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.4;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait){
    label.error { margin-left: 0; display: block; }
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape){
    label.error { display: inline-block; margin-left: 22%; }
}

em { color: red; font-weight: bold; padding-right: .25em; }


  </style>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$( "#frmLogin" ).validate({
    submitHandler: function( form ) {
        alert( "Call Login Action" );
    }
});

});//]]>

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<div data-role="page" id="login">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Acme Corporation</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">

        <form id="frmLogin" class="validate">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="email"><em>* </em> Email: </label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email"
                    class="required email" />
            </div>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="password"><em>* </em>Password: </label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password"
                    class="required" />
            </div>
            <div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                <button class="btnLogin" type="submit"
                    data-theme="a">Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Needless to say it's working *only* if I reload the form page after loading it or if I put data-ajax=false OR rel="external" on the link that leads to the form (losing jQuery animations)
I am going mad :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This the proper use of jQuery.validate in jQuery Mobile.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function () {
 $(form).validate({ // or form #id
  rules: {
   field: "required" // field name not #id and has class="required
   },
   submitHandler: function (form) {
    alert('data submitted');
    return false;
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: Afair your 1st row is wrong and should be:
$(document).bind('pageinit', function () {

Comment: @Pitto I have another solution which doesn't use jquery validation.

Comment: You talk about simple html5 validation?

Comment: It's a clever idea!
I've tried it but somewhat I am missing something... http://pitto.homeip.net/mobile (click on "inserisci clienti") and try

Comment: @Pitto your link isn't working, what error are you getting? Can you post both your markup and code.

Comment: @Pitto I went through the code but in couldn't identify the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

The validation should be applied on the **form** not in the input .Try the following :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myForm").validate(); // applying the validation on myForm
});
</script>
<form id="myForm">
<input type="text" id="field" name="field" class="required" required>
<input id="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Inserisci" data-theme="a"/>
<form>
```

for more infos : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

Comment: Sorry I missed that! Anyway I've tried your solution: same behaviour (see it if you want http://pitto.homeip.net/mobile)

Comment: you have to mark  at least one filed as required in order to activate the validation .
whic is not the case here view-source:http://pitto.homeip.net/mobile/inserisci_clienti.html

Comment: Oh sorry you probably got there while I was testing... Now is correct but the behaviour is the same... I'll stop messing sorry :)

Comment: in the three trials you are not selecting the form `$(insert).validate();` becomes `$('#insert').validate();` I suggest that you reed more about jquery selectors 
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion: I'll read it! I've tried your correction but the problems stays the same.
I've also tried with $(document).bind('pageinit', function ()
instead of the $(document).ready(function() but in both cases the validation is not happening, even using $('#insert').validate();

Comment: I've tried changing my form page with the one from here: http://www.elijahmanor.com/2011/02/jquery-mobile-form-validation.html and the problem is still there. So, definitely, I need to fix my index.html and not the form page. Question is... Where?

Comment: I've tried to rebuild from scratch with almost jQuery mobile documentation (and suggested tutorials) files...
everything is updated in the main question